# Under what title should I list my graduate program on my CV?

Tags: cv

I'm a PhD student, but wish to leave my current institution and am applying for PhD positions elsewhere. I'm not a PhD candidate yet, since I haven't still finished the courses and qualification exams that are required for candidacy. I was wondering if I should list my current program on my CV as

```
University of Stackexchange
Stack Exchanching, PhD
```

or just something like "graduate program" or nothing at all instead of "PhD".

I thought maybe I should list it as "MSc", because our department awards an MSc degree to PhD student if they complete the Master's courses, and I'll complete those courses before I move to my prospective PhD program.

Also, should I write an "expected" date? If yes, should that be the date I'd finish my PhD if I was staying here, or should that be the date I'll finish my 'integrated' MSc, or what?

Comment: Can you distinguish the terms [PhD] _student_ and _candidate_? (It seems they are country-specific.)

Answer (score 1):

You're applying for a PhD and you're on an MSc program (at least, the MSc part of a PhD program), so list your MSc program on your CV. (We could quibble over details, but MSc will be easily understood by all, whereas your precise situation seems overly complicated and possibly country specific.)

Write the expected completion date (for the MSc), because the reader of your CV wants to know when you're available to start a PhD.